# R no Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, linux

Utilizo o Python Jupyter Notebook. Quero passar a usar o R também na mesma plataforma. Sei que é possível, mas não descobri como.

Alguém poderia dar uma dica?

Comment: Quando preciso, utilizo a versão online e depois faço o download do notebook. Faça o teste, veja se não te atende: http://jupyter.org/try

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente o que você precisa fazer é instalar o [IRKernel](https://irkernel.github.io) que é equivalente ao IPython.

Para instalar basta rodar no R:

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
```

Depois (também no R) - para deixá-lo disponível.

```
IRkernel::installspec()
```

Mais informações [aqui](https://irkernel.github.io).

Comment: Ao final da instalação foram baixados 9 arquivos compactados... é necessário algum outro procedimento?

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/Rtmp2zgMwo/downloaded_packages’